# Does calling a ScriptableMember method on a Silverlight control from JavaScript create a new Instance of the control?

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight control with a method named `DoSomething()` decorated with the `<ScriptableMember()>` attribute. I then call this method *successfully* from JavaScript and proved by a little message box that apprears from the SL side that says "Method Called!".

Point is all that works. The problem I am having is that *prior* to calling this method I build up an ObservableCollection on the Silverlight control containing 1..n `FileInfo` objects. This works fine too and builds up as I add files to it. Each time I add a file, a messagebox tells me the count from Silverlight (i.e. "Count = 2").

Now the problem: when I call the method `DoSomething()` from JS and access that ObservableCollection the count = 0! To see what is going on I placed a message in the Silverlight control's constructor to see if it gets entered upon being called from JS, and indeed *it does* and appears to recreate the control.

If this is the case it kind of makes sense that my ObservableCollection has a count = 0 because it is not the same control instance where I built up the FileInfo collection.

So how in the world do I preserve the collection, and why would simply calling a method exposed to JS from Silverlight, recreate the control and not allow me to access it's given state? I don't want a new control, I need to manipulate it as-is. Or am I off base and doing something else wrong to cause this beahvior?

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: You are definitely off base.  You are clearly doing something wrong but in the complete absence of any code its impossible to say what that is.  Please include all relevant C# and js code (try to keep it short though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the instance registered was the culprit. The MSDN examples show registering a new instance of the type, but in my case I needed the actual instance of the Page Control itself which solved the problem.

So at the completion of my page's initialization, I could register the *current* page's instance like below:

```
HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("SLControl", Me)
```

This allowed me from JS to access the control in it's current state which included all objects in the ObservableCollection as required. I blogged about this topic with code examples and the article below expands on this situation:

Get A Silverlight Control's Current Instance For Communicating Via The HTML Bridge:
http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2012/03/get-silverlight-controls-current.html